# Is it possible to cover a zero-set a holomorphic function with a union of submanifolds?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $X$ be a complex manifold of dimension $d$ and assume that $f:X\to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and not identically equal to zero.

In this case the zero-set $X_1$ of $f$ is "almost" a submanifold of co-dimension $1$. Let $X_2$ be the subset of $X_1$ where $\nabla f =0$. Then $X_1\backslash X_2$ is an embedded submanifold of co-dimesnion $1$.

> Can we find an embedded submanifolds $Y$, of co-dimension at least $1$, which cover $X_2$?

If the answer is negative, here is what I hope to achieve. I am looking for a finite sequence $X_m\subset...\subset X_2\subset X_1\subset X_0=X$, such that $X_{k+1}$ is the intersection of $X_k$ and zero-sets of some functions (like $X_2$ is the intersection of $X_1$ with zero-sets of all partial derivatives of $f$),  $X_k\backslash X_{k+1}$ is an embedded submanifold of co-dimension $k$, and $X_m$ can be covered by an embedded submanifold.

From my understanding, something like this is called stratification of analytic sets, but I know approximately nothing on the topic.

PS in my specific case, $f$ is a Jacobian of a holomorphic map, but this is probably irrelevant.

Comment: No, you'll have to do a stratification by submanifolds of varying dimension, according to the singularities of $Z$. So only the top stratum will be open in $Z$. (Try the simplest example: $X=\Bbb C^2$, $f(x,y) = xy$.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I failed to state the question properly. Can we cover the subset of $Z$, where $\nabla f$ vanishes with an embedded submanifold?

Comment: Nope. That too needs to be stratified, in general. Imagine, for the simplest case, the solution set of $f(x,y,z)=xyz=0$. Then the singular set consists of the three coordinate axes, which all intersect at the origin. Varieties like the Whitney umbrella are even more subtle.